# Ponto em CSS abaixo de imagem

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho um carrossel de imagens. Cada imagem é uma logo svg de altura fixa e largura variável. Preciso colocar um ponto abaixo de cada imagem selecionada, para isso usei o seguinte código:

CSS:

```
footer .selecionado::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background-color: #009CE0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(50px);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="produto-logo selecionado">
    <img src="imagens/logos/erp.svg"/>
</div>
```

Resultado:

[image: imagem]

Porém dessa forma o ponto fica alinhado com o lado esquerdo da imagem. como posso fazer com que fique centralizado abaixo de cada imagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc tem que incluir a coordenada X no seu `transforn:translate()` também. Repare que agora tem 2 valores `(X, Y)`

Veja o modelo abaixo para entender melhor:

```css
.selecionado {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
footer .selecionado::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background-color: #009CE0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50px);
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="produto-logo selecionado">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/30"/>
    </div>
    <div class="produto-logo selecionado">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/150/30"/>
    </div>
    <div class="produto-logo selecionado">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/120/30"/>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: o `translate` antes não estava funcionando, o `width: auto; position: relative` resolveu o problema

Comment: @Pilati algumas coisas em CSS funcionam em cascata Pai/filho, por isso o pai com relative e o filho com absolute. Outras vezes quando a gente referencia algum valor no filho é preciso que o pai tb tenha algum valor. Isso não é regra absoluta, mas em alguns casos sem isso não da certo... Boa sorte ai tmj

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usar `transform` pode usar `top`. Usando `transform` você terá que usar prefixos (ex.: `-webkit`, `-ms`...) para funcionar em navegadores pre-modernos. Use `top: 50px` e para centralizar você usa `left: 50%` e  `margin-left: -5px` (metade do `width`). Veja o exemplo:

```css
.produto-logo{
   position: relative;
   width: 100px;
}

footer .selecionado::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background-color: #009CE0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
   <div class="produto-logo selecionado">
       <img height="40" width="100" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg"/>
   </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: estou usando o `transform` em outras partes do site, além disso a homologação está sendo feita apenas nas ultimas versões dos browsers

Comment: Perfeito então.